# vs2019 downloading Intellisense Index

Tags: intellisense

I am on VS 2019 Enterprise.  Just updated about two weeks ago.

Background tasks are forever showing "Downloading Intellisense index for nuget.org"

I am behind a firewall, so connecting to nuget.org for anything is not going to happen.

Is there anyway to disable downloading this intellisense index?

Answer (score 1):

Create an *DWORD (32-bit)* value called **Enabled** and set it to 0 under:

**HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_6cf1d688\Roslyn\Features\SymbolSearch**

The *'Roslyn\Features\SymbolSearch'* keys have to be created as well. The **'16.0_6cf1d688'** version number might be different on your machine.

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but there's no explanation, which would be nice!